# how to pause and resume a download in javafx

Tags: url, download, javafx, executorservice, resume

I am building a download manager in javafx

I have added function to download button which initialises new task.More than one download is also being executed properly.

But **I need to add pause and resume function. Please tell how to implement it using executor. Through execute function of Executors, task is being started but how do i pause & then resume it??**

Below I am showing **relevant portions of my code**. Please tell if you need more details. thanks.

Main class

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    public Button addDownloadButton;
    public Button pauseResumeButton;
    public TextField urlTextBox;
    public TableView<DownloadEntry> downloadsTable;
    ExecutorService executor;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        // here tableview and table columns are initialised and cellValueFactory is set

        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);
    }

    public void addDownloadButtonClicked() {
        DownloadEntry task = new DownloadEntry(new URL(urlTextBox.getText()));
        downloadsTable.getItems().add(task);
        executor.execute(task);
    }


    public void pauseResumeButtonClicked() {
        //CODE FOR PAUSE AND RESUME
    }
}
```

DownloadEntry.java

```
public class DownloadEntry extends Task<Void> {

    public URL url;
    public int downloaded;
    final int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE=50*1024;
    private String status;

    //Constructor
    public DownloadEntry(URL ur) throws Exception{
        url = ur;
        //other variables are initialised here
        this.updateMessage("Downloading");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void call() {
        file = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "rw");
        file.seek(downloaded);
        stream = con.getInputStream();

        while (status.equals("Downloading")) {
            byte buffer=new byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];

            int c=stream.read(buffer);
            if (c==-1){
                break;
            }
            file.write(buffer,0,c);
            downloaded += c;
            status = "Downloading";
        }
        if (status.equals("Downloading")) {
            status = "Complete";
            updateMessage("Complete");
        } 
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested in [Concurrency in JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm).

I guess you should also have a look at pattern [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

By the way I think you should not use constant string as a status ("Downloading", etc), creating an enum would be a better approach.

In your loop, around the read/write part, there should be a synchronization mechanism, controlled by your pause/resume buttons (see the two links).

Comment: i have changed comparison with string. But i have looked at your links and they don't seem to help me. Nothing is mentioned in the first link about how to puase a task.

Comment: Just as a proof of concept, you could add a volatile boolean attribute "isPaused" to your DownloadEntry, and check its state just after you create your buffer in the while loop. If the attribute "isPaused" is true, then you skip the read/write step.

Plus, you need a setter (for isPause), that you will use in your pause & resume buttons.

But I think that you want to be able to pause/resume all entries at the same time. That is why I was thinking about the Observer pattern (your DownloadEntry's should expect any event of pause/resume).